# Web SpeechRecognition stop completely

Tags: javascript, speech-recognition, webapi

I am using the Web API: SpeechRecognition to perform voice recognition in the browser. I am following the documentation found here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SpeechRecognition

I am detecting a keyword that the user says, if the users says that keepword, resolve the promise to true:

```
            if (interim_test_transcript.includes(keyword)) {
              console.log("requirement 2 met")
              resolve(true);
              recognition.abort();
              return;
            }
```

The problem is that even the `recognition.abort()` is executed, there is still the recording red dot in my browser tab, as if my browser is still recording. As shown in the figure below:
[image]

I have also tried `recognition.stop()`, the red recording dot is still there. I am wondering if the red dot means that my browser is still recording? If yes, how should I stop it completely? Such as destroying the recognition object? I do not want to give the impression to users that I keep recording them after the recording is finished.